# ACL Blocking domains/IPs in pfSense - Is it more efficient to null route from DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, firewall, access-control-list, pfsense

Starting to fine tune pfSense routers deployed at some businesses and in order to better protect privacy and security we started rolling out blocklists via pfBlockerNG.

Loading up lots of lists increases memory and cpu usage so I was thinking would it be best to just load the rules to the local DNS server (Windows Server 2016) and block by just nulling to 127.0.0.1?

The downside is dynamic rule sets would not be updated automatically.

From an business/enterprise standpoint is going in a certain direction better or is it just going to vary case by case?